# Can infinite dimensional vector spaces of functions have a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider $C^{\infty } (S) $ the space of infinitely continuously differentiable functions on a set $S$.

I Know that every infinitely differentiable function has a Taylor series, so for $f \in C^{\infty } (S) $ it's $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{f^{(n)} (a) }{n!} (x-a)^n$$ around $a$.

Can I consider the basis for $C^{\infty } (S) $ to be $\{ 1,x,x^2,... \} $?

Since every function on the set can be written as a linear combination of those infinitely many elements.

Comment: Not every smooth (infinitely differentiable) function has a Taylor series. But separate from that, infinite dimensional vector spaces having bases (Hamel bases) is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: What is an example of an infinitely continuously differentiable function that has no Taylor series?

Comment: Someone can correct me, but If I recall correctly, the canonical example is $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. In this case, $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable around $0$ and the taylor series around $a=0$ is always 0, which is not equal to $f(x)$ except at $x=0$.

Comment: @Kthamil Every infinitely differentiable function has a Taylor series, but only *analytic* functions have their Taylor series converge to the given function on some non-trivial interval. FeedbackLooper's example has a Taylor series, which is the same as the $0$ power series. The Taylor series even converges! It just doesn't converge to the function.

Comment: What if I consider the space of analytic functions, can the set $\{ ..., x^{-1}, 1,x,x^2 ,... \}$ be a basis?